# How to update a jar file after change in manifest file and lib folder?

Tags: java, hadoop, jar

I have `hadoop-1.0.3.jar`. I made few changes in lib folder(add external jar) and manifest file now i want to rebuild jar file with name `hadoop-1.0.4.jar`.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: so why r u not create jar file?what problem u have faced?

Comment: oye question me kush dal to de ki kya kiya tune ab tak,kush samajh aa raha hai isase?

Comment: I am using hadoop-1.0.4 with eclipse indigo so i want hadoop-1.0.4 jar file for eclipse plugin. According to hadoop tutorial if we can change in jar file than it is compatible with hadoop-1.0.4. so i want to change in jar and rebuild the jar.

Comment: but u should add this above..

Comment: gud..u know everything..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the shell, run:

`jar cvfm hadoop-1.0.4.jar Manifest.txt [list of files you want to package into your jar file]`

You can run `jar --help` in the shell to check the different options available.

Basically, this particular command means:

-c: Create new jar file.

-v: Verbose output.

-f: Specify the packaged file name.

-m: Include the manifest file.

The rest should be fairly easy to understand (output name, manifest file, list of files to be packaged).

Comment: @ Stegrex i have four folder(classes,lib,META-INF,resources) and 1 xml document. Manifest.MF is inside the META-INF folder .i have tried as u say it give java.io.filenotfoundexception. plz suggest me how to solve this problem..